# Diagnostics SQL which both Oracle and MSSQL understand

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, oracle, webforms

We envision a Diagnostics-process in a ASP.NET WebForms application (.NET4, C#): we dispatch end-to-end a diagnostics signal from UI into the database to verify that all layers of our web-architecture are alive and well. Until now we supported Oracle and invoked

```
SELECT * FROM DUAL
```

ultimately. Going forward we will support MSSQL, we will invoke

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

Does anyone know a universal SQL which would work on any Oracle and MSSQL instance out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are after is for a SQL statement to execute successfully, then you can use something benign like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

See this link on [INFORMATION_SCHEMA support](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/666.cfm)

To use this query in Oracle, you will first have to create the schema and table, even if it only has 1 column with no data.. just to get count(*) working.  In going that route, it may be even better to just create a dummy table and count from it rather than from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

Comment: Oracle does NOT have an INFORMATION_SCHEMA by default. It is possible to create your own, based on the views (such as ALL_TABLES) that Oracle does support

Comment: I would delete the answer if I could - it doesn't let me. So I edited it instead.